# Check if a binary registry value exists via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, registry

I have a code which checks for a registry key value that exists or not. It only works on none binary values, if the target path is a binary value then it can not checks for it and will tell that the key does not exists.

Here is the Code:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Stranger"
strValueName = "TargetBinaryKey"
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue

If IsNull(strValue) Then
WScript.Echo "The Key Does Not Exists."
Else
WScript.Echo "The Key Exists."
End If
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.enumValues` instead of `.GetStringValue`.  You can find a [code snippet here](http://activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/registry/#EnumRegVals.htm)

Addition: you could also use `GetBinaryValue` if you know at forehand that the value is [stored as binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks For your Reply AutomatedChaos. It is working well. Nice Job ;)